# SpringBoot tokenRepository,JdbcTokenRepository not save in table persistence_logins

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, jdbc, spring-security

Login work, but table persitence_logins remain empty.
I Follow the documentation here :
https://courses.baeldung.com/courses/learn-spring-security-the-starter-class/lectures/924437
Don't know how to change.
I need to Override something else ?

persistent_logins
username varchar(64) not null,
series varchar(64) primary key,
token varchar(65) not null,
last_used timestamp not null

SECURITY CONFIG

```
package com.example.java.configuration;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{


    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private final String USERS_QUERY = "select email, password, active from user where email=?";
    private final String ROLES_QUERY = "select u.email, r.role from user u inner join user_role ur on (u.id = ur.user_id) inner join role r on (ur.role_id=r.role_id) where u.email=?";


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .usersByUsernameQuery(USERS_QUERY)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(ROLES_QUERY)
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/dottore").hasAuthority("DOTTORE")
                .antMatchers("/home/**").hasAnyAuthority("USER").anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").usernameParameter("email").passwordParameter("password")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home/home")
                .and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .and().rememberMe()
                .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
                .tokenValiditySeconds(60*60)
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access_denied");
    }

    public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
        JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl db = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
        db.setDataSource(dataSource);

        return db;
    }
}



APPLICATION PROPERTIES 
#Peristence


spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=pass


# hibernate configurations
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialet= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

# thumeleaf configurations
spring.thymeleaf.mode= LEGACYHTML5
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

USER CONTROLLER:

```
package com.example.java.controller;


import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


import com.example.java.model.User;
import com.example.java.service.UserService;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.Threads;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


@Controller
public class UserController  {


    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;


    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView main(){
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("user/login");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value= {"/login"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

        model.setViewName("user/login");
        return model;
    }




    @RequestMapping(value= {"/signup"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView signup() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        User user = new User();
        model.addObject("user", user);
        model.setViewName("user/signup");

        return model;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value= {"/signup"}, method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView createUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult) throws InterruptedException {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        User userExists = userService.findUserByEmail(user.getEmail());

        if(userExists != null) {
            bindingResult.rejectValue("email", "error.user", "This email already exists!");
        }
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            model.setViewName("user/signup");
        } else {
            userService.saveUser(user);
            model.addObject("msg", "User has been registered successfully!");
            model.addObject("user", new User());
            model.setViewName("user/signup");




        }

        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value= {"/home/home"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView home() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        //Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User user = userService.findUserByEmail(auth.getName());

        model.addObject("userName", user.getNome() + " " + user.getCognome());
        model.setViewName("home/home");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value= {"/access_denied"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView accessDenied() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("errors/access_denied");
        return model;
    }



}
```

Comment: Please post repository, service class and database config. Do you get any errors in logs while writing to database?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
RESOLVED.

In security config I put:

```
.and().rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("my-remember-me")
```

And in login.html

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="my-remember-me" id="remember-me" />
```